# How to override ValidateUser in Membership provider method

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, membership-provider, custom-membershipprovider

By default **Membership provider**  has a static method `ValidateUser` with parameter .Is there a way to add an overloading method to **Membership provider** for `ValidateUser`  with three parameter. There parameter is Boolean which will decided user is teacher or student in my case.

```
public static bool ValidateUser(string username, string password, bool blnTeacher);
```

I tried to add but **Membership**  class is read-only in  visual studio .
How can i can add `ValidateUser` with three parameter.

Answer (score 0):

`ValidateUser` is really just there to validate the password.

From the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membership.validateuser(v=vs.110).aspx):

> Verifies that the supplied user name and password are valid.

Chances are, you are using the wrong tool for the job, and another tool exists for your need:

What are you actually trying to validate here?
(i.e. what will happen depending on whether the user is a student or a teacher ?)